# Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable return null in Function App when debugging

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am debugging an Azure function app today and would have run the app at least 20 times with no issues at all with Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DCConnection") working perfectly (it returns the connection string to the db).  I then added a new function app to the solution and set it up the same as the first one (.Net 6.0, isolated).  When running this new function app the Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable fails and returns null.

What?  Much checking later, the local.settings.json is there in the project and gets copied to the bin folder.  The one in the bin folder is actually the correct once (copied from the project).  Grr!

I then went back to the first project and now it won't work either.  Cleaned the whole solution, deleted all the bin and obj folders, did a "dotnet restore -f", rebuilt everything - still no go!

Then I thought I would reboot the pc, still no luck.  I am currently at a loss as what to do as Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable always returns null when debugging.  Next will be hard coding the connection string in the app just to get the debugging running again.

When deploying the function app to Azure, everything works fine and the connection is returned and all is good.

Any ideas?

Out of interest here is the first section of the program.cs for this function app (which has been working earlier today):

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()

            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()

            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

                var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DCConnection");
```

Comment: Further to the above, I have been able to get things working.  I added another brand new function app to the solution and it does work (meaning I can retrieve the environment variable I am after).  Then, when testing both my other function apps, they both now work correctly!  I suspect some sort of dll hell going on somewhere - but where?
I do note that the brand new function app has a Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage that is a version 4.0.4 whereas my other two use 5.0.1.  Upgrading them all to 5.0.1 still works OK.  Hmm, weird, somethings not right.

Answer (score 0):

Glad @*OzTrak*, that you have solved the issue by upgrading the NuGet Package `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage` to the recent one `5.0.1`.

I can see there are no issues registered with the NuGet [Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Storage/5.0.1) with the version `4.0.4` in the .NET 6 Azure Functions.

This version `4.0.4` is released 1.5 Years back and then with the 2 newer stable versions further `5.0.0`, `5.0.1`. So, there might be some breaking changes in the previous version and there are no recent issues registered on the recent versions also with the .NET 6 Azure Functions.

If you find any issues or breaking changes in .NET Azure Functions Projects with any of the extensions/packages, then raise the ticket in the Official [Issues](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues) GitHub Repository of Azure Functions.

Comment: Yes, I will raise a ticket should an issue arise again, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my Environment variables were null when running locally, kind of out of nowhere.

It probably conflicted somewhere, what ended up working for me was changing

```
<None Update="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

into

```
<None Update="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

Maybe this will help someone in not spending half an hour trying to figure out what's wrong.